# ShareKit iOS - different content for different platforms

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I am trying to use ShareKit to share via email an HTML string and share on Facebook a regular stream containing an image and some text.

The sample project just shows how to share the same info for every platform(Twitter, Facebook, email) but I want to be able to share different content according to the platform.

```
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title: @"title"];
item.text = @"share text";
SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for something similar and found it in ShareKit's documentation:
http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/

What you are looking for (I believe) is sharing to a specific service provider, and not using that action sheet interface. That's what I've done to create different content for different platforms.

Code:

```
#import "SHKFacebook.h"
#import "SHKTwitter.h"

...

- (IBAction)shareOnFacebook {
    // Create an image item
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] title:@"A Girraffe!"];

    // Share the item on Facebook
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];

    return;
}

- (IBAction)shareOnTwitter {
    // Create a text item
    NSString *someText = @"This is a blurb of text I highlighted from a document.";
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:someText];

    // Share the item on Twitter
    [SHKTwitter shareItem:item];

    return;
}
```

Hope this helps!
Oded.

Answer (score 0):

My own experience: I succeeded in only sharing URLs on Twitter while sharing both URLs and images on Facebook.

What I did: I rewrote some of SHKItem's instance methods, such as:

```
//original
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image title: @"title"];
//new version
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem image:image url:aURL title: @"title"];
```

and other related methods. In this way whenever I created a SHKItem instance, I would be able to pass both URLs and images to the following classes that are going to handle the sharing issues.