# What's the best way to implement facebook on my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook, uiwebview

I've got just one simple silly question:

What's the best way to implement Facebook on my application?

- Add an easy UIWebView connecting to the Url of the Faceboook page I want to show;
- Implement the API I found in several answer all of you already gave in this forum.

Thank you for your help

Luigi

Comment: What do you mean by "implement Facebook"?

Comment: Actually that's not so clear, I'm sorry. I simply meant to allow the user to open a specific Facebook page and use it with all the functionality (login, tag pictures, and so on). Hope it sounds quite better now.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "it depends," but IMHO you're asking the wrong question.

A better question would be "which method of integrating with FB would result in a better experience for my users?" That is, would your users be best served by "framing" the standard FB web interface in a UIWebView? Or maybe they'd be happier with just a small piece of FB functionality embedded in your app, like the "upload to FB" function in iMovie. Once you decide exactly *what* you want to do, *how* to do it tends to be fairly obvious.

Which way to go depends on what your app does, and how your users will want to do it - and you know that part far better than the rest of us do! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm gonna develop an iPhone app for a third part, that's one of the reason why I was quite confused. Anyway, thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered something similar here:
[ShareKit iOS - different content for different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617448/sharekit-ios-different-content-for-different-platforms/4913906#4913906)

Basically, I used ShareKit which is very popular and indeed was a breeze to add. You can see how easy the code is, in the question above.

Cheers,
Oded.